# How would you authorize indvidual attributes when viewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

Looking to be able to authorize certain users to have the ability to view fields not just have restrictions on the entire object

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a good question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how it should look like. Please rework your question and add an example.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to help you, as part of the documentation:

> With Pundit you can control which attributes a user has access to update via your policies. You can set up a permitted_attributes method in your policy like this:

```
# app/policies/post_policy.rb
 class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
     def permitted_attributes
         if user.admin? || user.owner_of?(post)
             [:title, :body, :tag_list]
         else
             [:tag_list]
         end
    end
end
```

There is also a helper which can control permissions per action

`permitted_attributes(record, action = action_name)` which can be used instead.

Or, most probaby, you want to use scopes which define access to certain attributes.

From the documentation about scopes:

> Often, you will want to have some kind of view listing records which a particular user has access to. When using Pundit, you are expected to define a class called a policy scope. It can look something like this:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user  = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where(published: true)
      end
    end
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? or not record.published?
  end
end
```